# Browser always keeps cache

Tags: macos, google-chrome, caching, kohana

I'm working on a project for school, and have run into a problem.
My browser takes a very long time to re-read the files on the localhost server.
I'm on a mac using Google Chrome, but have seen the same problem with Safari and Firefox.
Using cmd+shift+r does not work, and even dumping the cache through the browser does nothing. All I seem to be able to do is wait untill it's fetched the latest files.

My project is built in Kohana 3.3.1, in case that might be relevant.

Comment: What makes you think it is the cache? How large are the files being downloaded? What is the bandwidth on your workstation - you might have a limited bandwidth of other users might be "hogging" it all.

Comment: I assume it's pretty low, since I'm working on localhost.

Comment: Assume what is low? Caches improve performance not slow it down. And only after content has been loaded. In a lot of cases its our assumptions that end up being the root cause of the issue. Double check the size of the data being downloaded. The time the that serve might required to "calculate"/load the data and if you're on sort of bandwidth limit.

Comment: I thought local servers like Wamp and Mamp didn't use bandwidth a all, since it works even when I'm not connected to the internet.

Comment: Everything has a "cost" - I missed that it was localhost. If its very long then it could well be the the web server software. I have no experience with Wamp/Mamp. ***I bet its not the cache causing the issue** Try performance metrics on that web server s/w. Good luck.